# What is preferred way of using QNetworkAccessManager for effective asynchronous downloads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, web-crawler, qnetworkaccessmanager

In Qt one `QNetworkAccessManager` is able to support 6 parallel downloads (at least, for Windows). So, in your app you can use several `QNAMs` with independent downloads. I've met some ads about commercial web crawlers. Their descriptions usually contain phrases about hundreds of threads for  multiple downloads. Is this amount reasonable for an ordinary CPU with 2 cores?

It it worth for speedup of web crawling to create more than 6 explicit threads with their own `QNAMs` and `QEventLoops` for synchronized (within worker threads) page downloading?

Comment: It depends on so many factors that only benchmarking different number of theads in your application's production setup can properly answer your question. Anyhow my guess is that yes you would probably benefit from more than 6 parallel downloads on a fast network, 6 was  a number chosen to address regular web browsing use cases.